# Ruby: How to set instance variables from a class method?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass, instance-variables

I'm not sure that's the right title for this question, but I don't know how else to ask it. I have classes that need to be registered globally so they can be called later. I have most of it working except for a very important part. When the child inherits from the parent class, it registers a new instance, but when the `on_message` class method is called, I can't figure out how to set the instance variables that I need.

```
class MyExtension < ExtensionBase

  on_message '/join (.+)' do |username|
    # this will be a callback function used later
  end

end

class ExtensionBase

  def self.inherited(child)
    MainAppModule.registered_extensions << child.new
  end

  def self.on_message(string, &block)
    # these need to be set on child instance
    @regex = Regexp.new(string)
    @on_message_callback = block
  end

  def exec(message)
    args = @regex.match(message).captures
    @on_message_callback.call(args)
  end

end

# somewhere else in the code, I find the class that I need...

MainAppModule.registered_extensions.each do |child|
    puts child.regex.inspect # this is nil and I dont want it to be
    if message =~ child.regex
      return child.exec(message)
    end
end
```

How can I design this so that the `@regex` will be set so I can access it within the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works, and I have added now the whole code that is executable. Just store the code e.g. in file `callexample.rb` and call it by `ruby callexample.rb`

The main difference of my solution to the question is that the call to `on_message` now creates the instance with the relevant arguments and registers the created instance. Therefore I have deleted the method `inherited` because I don't need it any more.

I have added some `puts` statements to demonstrate in which order the code works.

```
class MainAppModule                               ## Added class
  @@registered_extensions = []
  def self.registered_extensions; @@registered_extensions; end
end

class ExtensionBase
  attr_reader :regex

  def self.on_message(string, &block)
    MainAppModule.registered_extensions << self.new(string, block)
  end

  def initialize(string, block)
    @regex = Regexp.new(string)
    @on_message_callback = block
  end

  def exec(message)
    args = @regex.match(message).captures
    @on_message_callback.call(args)
  end
end

class MyExtension < ExtensionBase

  on_message '/join (.+)' do |username|
    # this will be a callback function used later
    puts "Callback of #{self} called."
    "returnvalue"
  end
end

# somewhere else in the code, I find the class that I need...
MainAppModule.registered_extensions.each do |child|
    puts "Value of regex: #{child.regex}" # this is no more nil
    message = '/join something'
    if message =~ child.regex
      puts "On match evalue 'child.exec(message)' to: #{child.exec(message)}"
    end
end
```